# How do I load a page into another page using google app engine

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, wsgi

app engine n00b here in much need of assistance,

Basically I want to implement the functionality of the jquery load function on the server side in a RequestHandler's get(). That is, right now I have a page that has something like this:

```
<div id='content'></div>

<script>
    $('#content').load('/someContent')
</script>
```

Instead of loading the ('/someContent') url in the javascript, id like to do it in the get() of the request handler for the page that content is loaded into and render the resulting html into a template for the response.

I hope that made sense! I have a feeling my terminology is way off...

Comment: Your get will always result in a new page. You can use jinja2 template inheritance to load page blocks (like te script) in a base template.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how are you rendering the pages, so I assume you're using *Jinja2* as it's the general recommendation. In that case, you could use the *include* statement, like this:

#### Content.html

```
<div id='content'></div>

<script>
    {{ include 'SomeContent.html' }}
</script>
```

#### SomeContent.html

```
jQuery(function() {
    // some code
})
```

This way, if you render *Content.html*, the result will have *SomeContent.html* embeded in the result :)

Comment: Hi Jaime,
Thank you for the quick response!
The problem is though '/someContent' is mapped to a handler which generates a dynamic page based off of info in the datastore so I dont think I can just provide a file. I want to be able to get the output of the handler mapped to '/someContent' and use that to render a new page.